# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el primer elemento con CSS?

Tags: html, css

bien dicen que no hay pregunta tonta así que aquí les hago la mía.

Tengo una lista de div's dentro de un div

```
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Quiero seleccionar el div con el número 1 con Css. Ya intenté el nth-child(1) y first-child.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nth-child(1) y first-child deberían funcionarte, probablemente hayas colocado algo mal en tu css. Seleccionar el primer div dentro del div con la clase container se puede hacer de diferentes manera:

```
/*seleccionarán el primer hijo div dentro de container y dentro de los hijos de container*/
.container div:nth-child(1){ }
.container div:first-child{ }
.container div:first-of-type{ }/*ignorará los elementos anteriores que no sean divs*/

/*seleccionarán el primer hijo div directo dentro de container*/
.container > div:nth-child(1){ }
.container > div:first-child{ }
.container > div:first-of-type{ }/*ignorará los elementos anteriores que no sean divs*/
```

Answer (score 6):

Prueba [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```css
div.container > div:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: Como han mencionado @asantana o y @Carlos Ormeño, tanto [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) como [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) deberían funcionar:

```css
div.container > div:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
```

```css
div.container > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Puedes utilizar la pseudo clase `:first-child` sobre el elemento que tiene varios hermanos;

```css
.container > div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>DIV 1</div>
  <div>DIV 2</div>
  <div>DIV 3</div>
  <div>DIV 4</div>
</div>
```